# How do I simplify this function so that I am able to sketch it and obtain the domain?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I have a function: $f(x,y) = y^2 + \ln(x^2) -1$.

I need to sketch this function and use the sketch to obtain the domain of the function, however, I cannot sketch the function if it is in the form given above, I need to simplify/rearrange it into to something I can sketch.

This is where I am having some issues. I'm not sure how I can simplify the above into something I can sketch, the only simplification I can see possible is to change $\ln(x^2)$ to $2\ln(|x|)$ but I don't think this helps.

Any suggestions on what simplification I could make or what process I would need to do to be able to sketch this function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are wrong when you claim that $\ln(x^2)=2\ln(x)$. What you do have is $\ln(x^2)=2\ln(|x|)$.

Comment: Of course $\ln(x^2) =2\ln|x|$ helps, and that is pretty much the onky simplification you can make.

Comment: To sketch this function, you can think of fixing $y$ to sketch the curve $2\ln|x|+ (y^2-1)$, and similarly fixing $x$ to sketch the curve $y^2 +(2\ln|x| -1)$. This will tell you how cross-sections of the surface must look like.

Comment: @Tavish What I was thinking was finding $y$ in terms of being greater than/less than $x$ (or the other way around). I think I worded that badly so let me explain. Let's say we had $ln(x^2 y^2)$ as our function, well we know this is greater than or equal to 0 since ln of any positive number is always positive. Well then I could say $x^2 y^2$>$1$. Then I would have $|xy|$ > $1$ and I would be able to find $y$ in terms of $x$, I would have $y$>$1/x$, $y$>$-1/x$, etc. Do you think we could do something similar here?

Comment: @CharlieP No, $x$ and $y$ have absolutely no relation here whatsoever. Also, the ln of any positive number need not be positive.

Comment: @Tavish Ok, and when you say fixing $y$ or $x$, do you mean just assigning them a random value? Will that work to sketch the graph?

Comment: @CharlieP Yes, just think of them as any constant. Then you can sketch the corresponding $2$D graph in the other variable.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say in this case it is easier *not* to sketch this function, but to look at this algebraically. The function $g(y)=y^2$ is defined for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$. The function $h(x)=\ln(x^2)$ is well-defined if $x^2>0$, i.e. if $x \neq 0$. Since $f(x,y) = g(y)+h(x)-1$, your function is well-defined for all $(x,y) \in (\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}) \times \mathbb{R}$, so that is your domain.

Comment: So basically my function is defined for all values except when $x=0$? Also, In regards to sketching the function I know it would be simpler to not sketch it but I would still like to be able to sketch it, if you know a way to sketch this I would really appreciate being shown it, otherwise don't worry.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I'm not sure how to sketch this function by hand either, I'd simply use an online 3d calculator for that.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot